# Bluebird Promise each: continue iteration if promise rejected

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

According to Bluebird promise online documentation, the "each-method" 
([LINK](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html)) stops iteration if one promise is rejected. Is there any way to make it continue and complete all iterations? 
If not, what should I use instead? I am looking for a way to:

- iterate sequentially over an array (that is: wait for previous promise to complete before continue with next iteration)
- always continue iteration even if some promise rejections occur
- be able to nest more than one loop

I've been working with this code so far but find it rather cumbersome and would like to switch to a lighter/native piece of code.

```
var promiseFor = Promise.method(function(condition, action, value) {
if (!condition(value)) return value;
   return action(value).then(promiseFor.bind(null, condition, action));
});

return promiseFor(function(count){
   return count < someArray.length;
}, function(count){

   //foo...       
   return ++count;
}, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would just be to throw in a `.catch(() => {})` function to recover from stuff that throws.

with a native approach just use some [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

```
async function doWork (array) {
  for (let value of array) {
    if (condition) break
    await action(value).catch(() => { /* recover */ })
  }
}
```

with async/await you can also use try/catch

```
async function doWork (array) {
  for (let value of array) {
    if (condition) break
    try {
      await action(value)
    } catch (err) { }
  }
}
```